# cant create remote log execution of my scripts

Tags: ansible

I m trying to run a remote script with ansible and i want to log on the remote servers some point. My script is very basic as :

```
cd /somewhere
servername=`hostname -f`
echo $servername >> ansible.log
echo "begin of the section" >> ansible.log ##
...
echo "var ..." >> ansible.log
```

but the echo content is never logged to my ansible.log

`cat /file  >> ansible.log` works fine

How would be possible to log the actions of my scripts, echos , variables , messages to local / host logs ?
thanks

Comment: Hi user11756453, welcome to SO. Are you already aware than ansible logs all actions into syslog, unless directed not to do so? And if that's insufficient for you, are you already aware of [ara](https://github.com/ansible-community/ara#readme) and/or [Tower/awx](https://github.com/ansible/awx#readme)?

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of options for logging in Ansible ([callbacks](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/callback.html#plugin-list), plugins, utils ...)

In your particular case the play below

```
- hosts: test_01
  tasks:
    - script: test1.sh
```

with the script

```
$ cat test1.sh 
#!/bin/sh
cd /scratch
servername=`hostname -f`
echo ${servername} >> ansible.log
echo "begin of the section" >> ansible.log
```

creates file */scratch/ansible.log* at host *test_01*

```
root@test_01:~ # cat /scratch/ansible.log
test_01
begin of the section
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi thanks for the answer
for some reason redirection was not working properly 
i have created a full path to a place as:

logfile=/tmp/debug_log_$start.log
echo "start " `date +%m-%d-%Y-%H-%M-%S` > $logfile

and this works now :)